# How to create Image Input Levels(Output) on js?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, fabricjs

How to create Image Input Levels(Output) ? I have Image on canvas...and i must correct it levels by created 
`<input type="range" id="imageInputWhite" value="0" min="0" max="255" class="auto-bind"><br/>`

Comment: question is not clear

Answer (score 0):

Question is really a little unclear, but from what I read here:

- Bind a change event listener against your range input
- Be sure to setup a levels filter for your canvas image
- On every change adjust the needed parameters of your filter
- Call applyFilters after that
- If needed call renderAll on the canvas.